# Perform an operation with complete cases without changing the original vectors

Tags: r

I would like to calculate a rank-biserial correlation. But the (only it seems) package can't handle missing values that well. It has no built in "na.omit = TRUE" function. I could remove the missings in the data frame, but that would be a hustle with many different calculations.

```
n <- 500
df <- data.frame(id = seq (1:n),
                 ord = sample(c(0:3), n, rep = TRUE), 
                 sex = sample(c("m", "f"), n, rep = TRUE, prob = c(0.55, 0.45))
)
  
df <- as.data.frame(apply (df, 2, function(x) {x[sample( c(1:n), floor(n/10))] <- NA; x} ))

library(rcompanion)
wilcoxonRG(x = df$ord, g = df$sex, verbose = T)
```

I imagine something stupidly easy like "complete.cases(wilcoxonRG(x = df$ord, g = df$sex, verbose = T)). It's probably not that hard but I could only find comeplete data frame manipulations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `with(df[complete.cases(df),], wilcoxonRG(x = ord, g = sex, verbose = TRUE))`?

Comment: Or `with(na.omit(df), ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, works well! Gotta remember "with()".

Comment: `with` and `within` are very useful, providing NSE-like operations for "regular" functions.